# How to add a static field to gelf logstash appender in properties file? biz.paluch.logging

Tags: java, logstash, log4j2, gelf

I am using [GELF-logstash appender](https://logging.paluch.biz/) together with `log4j2` as logging appender, to send logs from my application through logstash to ElasticSearch/Kibana.
In each log message I want to configure a static field, namely the region my application is deployed to, which is gathered from an environment variable differing by the region the application is running in.

I found out that Static Literals are supported by the XML configuration like this: `<Field name="fieldName1" literal="your literal value" />` https://logging.paluch.biz/examples/log4j-2.x.html
But I would like to stay with my `log4j2.properties` file based configuration if possible, but could not find a documentation to add a static literal there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can use the pre-defined field `facility`, or define as many custom static fields as you wish in your `log4j2.properties` file:

```
# required configuration for GELF
appender.gelf.type = Gelf
appender.gelf.name = GELF
appender.gelf.host = ${sys:LOG_HOST}
appender.gelf.port = ${sys:LOG_PORT}

# pre-defined field facility
appender.gelf.facility = a_static_value

# custom static field using environment variable
appender.gelf.environment.type = Field
appender.gelf.environment.name = environment_logging_field_name
appender.gelf.environment.literal = ${sys:ENV_VAR_NAME}

# custom static field with static value
appender.gelf.secondfield.type = Field
appender.gelf.secondfield.name = fieldName
appender.gelf.secondfield.literal = your_value_here
```

Comment: You cannot use the system property lookup to access an environment variable. ${sys:ENV_VAR_NAME} needs to be ${env:ENV_VAR_NAME}

Comment: works on my machine ;). But I think you are still right, that `env` sounds better.